# Is it OK to go stateful in Play for Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, ehcache

In my Play 2.x web application I have a requirement to list all the users that logged in, the time they started the session, the time of their last action, and if there's a period of N minutes since their last action, terminate the session.

One way to achieve it is to use the cache (Play uses EHCache). But what I learned is that **it's not a good thing to have stateful information on server side** (one of the strengths of Play 2 is that the framework is stateless).

What is the best way to support my requirements?

Comment: You may just save login time in play's `session` (which actually is a simple string in cookie). Then verify that session everytime in `ActionBuilder` of `Filter`.

Comment: I prefer not to save information in a cookie at client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends...  Can the state be recreated from a durable store?  If so then use a cache (either in-memory or external e.g. Memcached).  If not then you should use an external durable data store.

Comment: What's a durable store? a database? I won't store the state in a database, why would I store the user last action in a database? Apparently is not a bad practice to store session data in a cache.

Comment: A durable store is a place you can put state and be sure that you can get it back out at any point in the future.  This can be a relational database, a NoSQL database (e.g. Mongo), or a variety of other things.  If you can easily recreate the state or if you don't care about losing it, then you don't need to put it in a durable store.  A cache is a non-durable store.